# How to display all the events in a week view of a calendar?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have calendar installed on my site.
I have created a content type named events.
The events content type has three fields title, event time(time only not date and its of type time) and day.

I have modified the block of the calendar view. I have selected the week from calendar format settings so that it should display the week view.

Now I want to list all the events under the monday which have the monday selected in the day field, all the events under the tuesday which have the tuesday selected in the day field and so on.

**Format:**

Mon              tue                 Wed                 Thu    Fri                 Sat                 Sun

event1          event2

Monday        Tuesday

2:30              2:30

Answer (score 1):

Calendar module creates a node for each day.So all you need to do is create a field of type date in your content type and then create nodes.

Alternatively,you can try using jquery fullcalendar plugin(http://code.runnable.com/UfNTSnKMU1ZgAACt/how-to-add-calendar-using-jquery-and-fullcalendar) and provide data for each day programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a view with. The FORMAT could be "Table" and you have to use on the setting "Grouping field Nr.1".

On Grouping field Nr.1 you can select your day field.

I hope it's what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I want to use the calendar module. And the current events which I have created will be repeated for all the weeks. And in the future there will be some events which will be displayed in their perspective week only.

Comment: Are you using date repeat?

Comment: Yes I have installed the the date repeat api module. But does not know how to modify the view to repeat the events.

Comment: On the date field of your content type you should give the option of the Repeating date

Comment: there is no date field. One is day field and the other is time field

Comment: I think you should switch to date field in order to get what you want. There you can use the repeating option and get the calendar style.